# MySQL server doesn't put update value inside ' and ' so it think the value is a column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just installed MySQL 5 on my server and imported a database from another server.
Now when I tried to make a simple INSERT command with MySQL Workbench I got this from my server:

```
ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'Test1' in 'field list'
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `myTable`.`helpanswer` SET `Answer`=Test1 WHERE `id`='6'
```

When I, from a previous EDIT command, right clicked on the field "Answer" in a row, changed it, and pressed the "Apply all changes to data" button.

When I do this on the orginal server everything works fine.

Are there some setting I must change on my server to get this to work?

I dont get it why my server doesn't put "Test1" inside 'Test1' like it should...

I know I can use the UPDATE command but to be able to just right click the field and click a button saves me alot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct query should be:

```
UPDATE `myTable`.`helpanswer` 
    SET `Answer` = 'Test1' WHERE `id`='6'
```

This is because `Test1` is a string and must be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Yeah it's a string and the UPDATE command works fine but as I said I can't edit the field with MySQL Workbench, the program itself doesn't enclose Test1 with quoutes so Mysql doesn't read it as a string... :(

Comment: @theSwede: sorry, what do you mean with your previous comment?

Comment: Marco, sorry, don't know how that comment made it here. :P (Deleted).
Any more input on why Mysql doesn't enclose the value inside quotes?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is picky about quotes. Try this:

```
UPDATE `myTable`.`helpanswer` SET `Answer`='Test1' WHERE `id`='6'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But if I use the UPDATE command it works fine but I can't edit the field with a right click and the button "Apply changes" and I don't understand why that don't work when it does with the exact same schema and table on another server.. I just installed MySQL 5 on my server so I wonder if there is something I need..?